# Simple selection sort in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I've seen the following code for the selection sort algorithm in Python, my question is more to do with the functionality of python than the algorithm.

---

```python
def Selectionsort(A):

  for i in range (0,len(A)-1):

    minIndex=i
    for j in range (i+1,len(A)):
     if A[j]<A[minIndex]:
      minIndex=j
    if minIndex !=i:
     A[i],A[minIndex]=A[minIndex],A[i]



A=[10,7,6,4,5,3,1,8,2,9]:         

Selectionsort(A)

print(A)
```

---

My question is why after applying Selectionsort(A) does the new A equal the original A but in the sorted order? Why does Print(A) not return the original A?

how do i get my code to indent like it does written in the programme after pasting it?

Comment: The code in question does destructive modification of `A` list, specifically in the line `A[i], A[minIndex]=A[minIndex],A[i]`. But this is really badly written piece of Python code (it violates coding conventions several times per line).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the tag programming-languages, which is about the design, implementation and analysis of PL. Also, programming questions should be posted to StackOverflow, not CS.

Comment: @chi There's not much point complaining about the tags: off-topic questions have inappropriate tags almost by construction.

Answer (score 0):

I feel bad when I see code written in an actual programming language as if it was Pascal-pseudocode nonsense, so here's how the original idea of this code would look like if written using Python coding conventions:

```python
def selection_sort(unsorted):
    for i in range(len(unsorted) - 1):
        min_index = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(unsorted)):
            if unsorted[j] < unsorted[min_index]:
                min_index = j
        # You don't really need this if, if you don't check
        # for this condition, the swap is going to be a noop
        if min_index != i:
            # This line swaps two elements of `unsroted' list
            # by destructively modifying it
            unsorted[i], unsorted[min_index] = unsorted[min_index], unsorted[i]
        print unsorted
    return unsorted
```

Still, this is very non-idiomatic Python, a more Python-like code would be something like this:

```python
def selection_sort(unsorted):
    for i in range(len(unsorted) - 1):
        idx = min(enumerate(unsorted[i:]), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
        unsorted[i], unsorted[i + idx] = unsorted[i + idx], unsorted[i]
    return unsorted
```